# Is it possible to run firebase messaging in node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

under nodejs i did :

```
npm install firebase --save
```

then i do

```
  var firebase = require("firebase");

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...,
    databaseURL: "....",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "...."
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging(); << crash here
```

but it's crash saying `firebase.messaging is not a function`

Is their any way to run firebase messaging in node.js to listen notification ?
their is the file `/node_modules/firebase/firebase-messaging.js` but it's obfuscate and i can't understand it and what it's does

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#npm: _"Firebase Cloud Messaging is not included in the server side Firebase npm module"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two Firebase SDKs that will work on Node:

- the [Firebase Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), which is targeted towards client-side devices such as browsers and Node.js IoT devices.
- the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which is meant to run on trusted devices, such as a Node.js server that you host.

Support for [sending messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging is **only** included in the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/).

Supporting for receiving messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging is **only** included in the Firebase Web SDK. It is not possible to receive FCM messages in Node.js.

If you want to send message **to** a Node.js process, I'd recommend you look into the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Comment: thanks franks, but i can't run on nodejs the Firebase Web SDK, which is targeted towards client-side devices such as browsers and Node.js :(

Comment: That is correct. There is no way to securely send FCM messaging from one client device directly to another client device. You'll need a trusted process to do the sending. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: to do the sending it's not a problem, my server will do it ... however i would like that the client runing on nodejs (or anything else) can receive the message

Comment: Aaahhh... that was not clear to me. I expanded my answer to include that, but the answer is a "nope".

Comment: thanks Frank ... do you have an idea if it's could be possible and how i can receive message using javascript WITHOUT a browser ? i would like to use fcm in my c++ windows software and i was thinking to interface it with javascript

Comment: but this is for iOS and Android :(