# Receive mobile app notifications through Node.js

Tags: node.js, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to receive the notifications from a schedule based game and post them into a Discord channel. For example they are something like "Hey join now!" when the game is live, or updates to the games schedule.

Comment: Where is the code of your node server where you want to push a notification to all the devices?

Comment: @UmarHussain I do not want to push notifications from a server, I want to receive them like a client.

Comment: There is no Admin SDK for *receiving* FCM messages in Node.js. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936730/is-it-possible-to-run-firebase-messaging-in-node-js. You could use another product (e.g. Firebase Database or Cloud Firestore) for communicating with a Node.js process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run firebase messaging in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936730/is-it-possible-to-run-firebase-messaging-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the document for FCM to send notification from your server adn receiving at your client side.
FCM supports all major platforms.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

If you have any further queries, please ask them after implementing, so that community can better help you out.